# How to disable HDD lock in BIOS?

Tags: bios, secure-boot

I have an Acer Spin 3 laptop with Secure Boot. I was messing around in BIOS and now the laptop asks for a HDD password upon boot. It is annoying, how do I disable it again?

The BIOS is Insyde H20 rev 5.0. Thanks.

Comment: Go into the BIOS and delete the password.

Comment: "I was messing around in BIOS"... hmmm....

Comment: Yes, deleting the password (or creating a blank password) was all I needed to do.